# Can I convert from C# to asp.Net to host application online?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, web-hosting

Is it possible to convert a C# application into an asp.Net webpage? All i want to do is display the application in a website of mine!? The website is made in flash and if i choose to open the application directly it downloads the .exe which is not what i pretend.

Edit: Application has only about 30 buttons and has one additional form besides first one.

Comment: Convert a C# WinForms app to an ASP.NET WebForms app?

Answer (score 4):

All of your standard C# classes/libraries should migrate over smoothly.  What you're going to have a tough time with is converting the (presumably) winforms user interface into a fully-functional web interface.  There is no direct conversion, but most winforms controls have an approximate web equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good potential candidate for the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx). This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9307/Converting-WinForms-Web-Forms-using-CodeDom) should point you in the right direction; it demonstrates how to convert a windows form to a web form, and appears to do it quite successfully from the screenshots.

At the end of the day, it may be easier to just handle it manually. Unless this is a very simple application, you'll probably have to bite the bullet and DIY.

Comment: Seems like it should to the work. Will mark as correct if i manage to do it (: thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest answer to this question is, no. Desktop app and web apps have completely different structure even though you can use C# in the code behind. There's no simple way to convert a desktop app project to an ASP.net project that I know of.

Comment: waw you have gold medals! So it means i have to do it from square 0 ? :( makes me real sad .

Comment: It's not easy, but it is definitely possible for a simple app.

Comment: @Bruno, I'm just saying that it's not so easy to just simply convert a  desktop app to an ASP.Net project. You could alleviate some of the pain by sharing a DLL with common classes and business logic. Other than that, it's a completely different type of UI.

Comment: thing is, creating the layout seems to be a real challenge considering asp is really clunky imo.